# How to register events handler after the page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I hope I'm making the question clear.

Say you have some check-boxes (or any other type of element for that matter) for which you register events handler when the page loads. Then you add some more check-boxes using AJAX (so no page reload). But you also want these newly added check-boxes (after the page was loaded) to have the same registered events handlers?

What I tried was this but I feel there has to be a better approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Register custom envets handler
  registerCustomEventHandlers();

  $('a').on('click', addExtraFields);
});

function registerCustomEventHandlers() {
  $('input.class_name').on("change", sayHelloWorld);
}

function sayHelloWorld() {
  alert('Hello world');
}

function addExtraFields() {
  // insert some checkboxes...

  // register the events handler again for the newly added fields
  registerCustomEventHandlers();
}
```

So basically inside the function that adds the check-boxes I register again all the events handlers. I was looking at something like this `$(document).change(function() {});` but apperently it is not supported by all browsers...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate the event to the `document` instead so that they will be applied to all future inputs as well. You don’t even need to put it in a `domReady` event, since the `document` is always available:

```
$(document).on("change", "input.class_name", sayHelloWorld);

function sayHelloWorld() {
    alert('Hello world');
}

function addExtraFields() {
    // insert some checkboxes, they will have the same handler attached when inserted
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gdX3R/1/

Comment: Thanks for the live example. It's exactly what I need and sorry for the late vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using live selectors because of [these reasons](http://shaneriley.tumblr.com/post/1679999567/when-you-should-use-jquerys-live-and-delegate-methods)

Shortly summed up, it's a performance issue because it messes with every click event.

Instead, just use delegate like described in the post on lowest common parent element of the inputs (most likely a form):

```
$('#yourFormId').delegate('.class_name', 'click', function() { 
   // what you want to do
});
```

You can find [a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eqYhw/)

And don't use selectors like input.class_name (unless there elements other than input with that class name). They're slower than .class_name because they're looping through all the inputs in the form searching for elements with that class rather than just selecting by class.

Comment: I can only choose one best answer but I like this solution as well. So +1 from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of jquery 1.4 you can always use `live()` too http://api.jquery.com/live/ which allows you to attach handlers now and in the future to any matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

the way this is done in Jquery is such that  you don't need the object to be present when creating the handler.

You could use:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", 
   function(){alert($(this))}
);
```

This will be applied to any new check-box added to the page, no matter timing.